# How to make moviePlayer fullscreen?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I make the movie player fullscreen like Snapchat app? Have a look at this picture:

[image]

I want to remove the "Done" bar and "Play - Pause " bar and make it fullscreen player.

Any idea, tips, help?

I'm using: Xcode beta 7 with Swift 2.

Comment: What you have done so far? share some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `MPMoviePlayerController` (or `MPMoviePlayerViewController`), you can set `controlStyle` to `None`.

Comment: Thank you for help, I've did that like this : moviePlayer.fullscreen = true , but the bars still showing, I wrote that after self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)

Comment: Oops, sorry, brain freeze. Updated the answer, you should set `controlStyle` to `None`, not `fullscreen`.

Comment: Thank you so much i really appreciate  it, problem solved!